# Laravel sanctum with react same domain 401 authentication error using cookies

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

Authenticating with the sanctum token is working just fine but sadly I can't get it to work using cookies instead (calling `/api/user` returns `401 Unauthorized`). I'd really like to make use of the cookie authentication because it's safer.

Does anyone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong (or missing) to make the authentication work based on cookie so the frontend doesn't have to send sanctums bearer token?

### **Setup**

I'm running React outside of Laravel but both the laravel backend and the react frontend are running on the same domain under subdomains (`api.website.com` and `customer.website.com`).

#### **.env**

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=.website.com
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000,.website.com
```

#### **kernel.php**

```
'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

#### **session.php**

```
'same_site' => 'lax',
'http_only' => true,
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

'cookie' => env(
  'SESSION_COOKIE',
   Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
 ),
```

#### **cors.php**

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://api.website.com', 'https://customer.website.com'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['x-csrf-token', 'x-xsrf-token', 'content-type'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

#### **UserController.php**

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$request->email) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Missing email'], 401);
        } elseif (!$request->password) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Missing password'], 401);
        } elseif (!$request->device_name) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Missing device_name'], 401);
        } else {
            $credentials = $request->validate([
                'email' => ['required', 'email'],
                'password' => ['required'],
            ]);

            if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                $auth = Auth::user();
                $token = $auth->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
                $auth->setAttribute('token', $token);

                return response()->json($token, 200);
            }

            return response()->json(['error' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.'], 401);
        }
    }
```

#### **Api.php**

```
// Force all API responses to be in JSON format.
Route::middleware('json.response')->group(function () {
    
    // UNAUTHENTICATED API's.
    Route::post('login', [UserController::class, 'login']);

    // AUTHENTICATED API's.
    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
        // USER.
        Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
            return $request->user();
        });


        // ADMIN.
        Route::middleware('role.admin')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/migrate', function () {
                artisan::call('migrate');
                return response()->json("success", 200);
            });

            Route::get('/route/clear', function () {
                artisan::call('route:clear');
                return response()->json("success", 200);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

#### **Frontend**

```
const instance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
});

const loginWithEmailPasswordAsync = async (email, password) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-await
  return await instance
    .post('https://api.website.com/api/login', {
      email,
      password,
      device_name: '_device',
    })
    .then((res) => {
      return instance
        .get('https://api.website.com/api/user')
        .then((user) => {
          return user;
        })
        .catch((error) => error);
    })
    .catch((error) => error);
};

 try {
    instance
      .get('https://api.website.com/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
      .catch((error) => error);

    const loginUser = yield call(loginWithEmailPasswordAsync, email, password);....
```

#### **Request and response headers when the 401 Unauthorized error pops up**

Not sure if it matters but in my browser network tab I do see what seems to be the correct request headers such as the filled in `X-XSRF-TOKEN`, `Cookie` and in the response headers the `set-cookie` = `laravel_session=ySiTVYYvyFKHSt9Q0VnP2vl4xeIee0MnjvlfQSu4; expires=Tue, 02-Aug-2022 18:55:13 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=.website.com; httponly; samesite=lax`

Comment: something is confusing me, you said you wanted to use sanctum cookie based authentication, which is for SPA application. so why are you issuing sanctum api token in your login function?. cookie based auth uses cookies not api token. am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS from this

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000,.website.com
```

to this:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000,customer.website.com
```

Comment: That sadly didn't work. The `.website` should be fine though as wildcard for all subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll have different .env for your dev and production environment, I think  you should remove localhost host totally.
You can change your code from

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000,.website.com
```

To

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=website.com,frontend-subdomain-if-any.website.com
```